# Lubuntu 20.04LTS shows condensed fonts in web browsers

Tags: 20.04, fonts, browser

I've just installed Lubuntu 20.04LTS, but I cannot figure out why it uses condensed fonts.

This is the effect in Firefox:

[image: This is the effect in Firefox]

this is the effect in Chromium:

[image: this is the effect in Chromium].

Any hint on how to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized the problem was introduced by some fonts I --brutally-- copied in ~/.fonts. After removing the whole directory, the problem disappeared. Whoohoo!

Comment: Don't forget if you modify/add/remove fonts, the font-cache needs to be re-create using the `fc-cache` command (ie. *update the index of what fonts are available on your file-system*)